# Putting PHP and Rails on the same server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, apache2

I am currently working on a website where the core of the website is in PHP. I now want to write a bunch of applications on top of that core, and was hoping to do it in Rails. I saw a couple things online where you could set single folders to be handled by PHP, (example: http://macdiggs.com/2007/06/29/using-php-inside-rails-structure-on-apache/) but I am hoping to do the opposite, have single folders that are handled by Rails, and then the rest is handled by PHP. For example, having ourwebsite.com/blog as a Rails app, but ourwebsite.com and ourwebsite.com/internal are all in PHP. What kind of Apache configurations would let this happen?

(As a bonus, my server is managed by Plesk, so I am concerned about making straight changes to the apache configuration. I have root access, so I can do it, but I am worried that Plesk might get mad)

EDIT: I should also mention, I am using Subdomains as part of my application, so I would really prefer to have something like ourwebsite.com/rails_app. If that is the only option, I can go that route, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the PHP app to be default application and only use Rails for a subdirectory, this Apache configuration should work for you:

```
DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/php/app/html"
ProxyPass /some_resource http://127.0.0.1:3000/some_resource
```

Note that your rails application would be running on port 3000 and you will need the ProxyPass Apache module installed.

Comment: Hello Andrew, can you help a bit by what you mean by 'running on port 3000'. how do you run a rails app on server?

Answer (score 3):

I am working on a project and its having some blog in php ie wordpress and application in rails. Just configured it an hour before. Might help you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName abc.com
DocumentRoot /home/me/apps/my_rails_app/current/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.abc.com
DocumentRoot /home/me/apps/abc/wordpress
 <Directory "/home/me/apps/abc/wordpress">
        Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have mentioned, part of the application is being able to have your own subdomain, so these need to be in the form abc.com/rails_app. I am editing the question to better reflect this.